# Heap corruption after second use of strcat

Tags: c++

This is driving me nuts because I'm not seeing what bonehead mistake I'm making here.

In the following snippet (note this is just a test snippet is from a larger method), I'm basically just attempting to copy a string that's retrieved from a SQL method, and then if the user specifies in the method an additional number of columns, append a delimiter (in this case a semi-colon) and the additional string:

```
//...
char** pLocalArray;
char buff[512];
//... pLocalArray is allocated

// The semicolon is replaced by a variable passed into the function, but just putting this for simplicity
char delimeterStr[2] { ';', '\0' };

for (int uCol = 0; uCol < numCols; uCol++)
{
    if (uCol >= 1)
    {
        const char* test2 = "1704EB18-FE46-4AE4-A90F-06E42C3EE07A"; // Just a test GUID
        memcpy(buff, test2, 37); // Just testing some logic, copy the string into the buffer 

        strcat(pLocalArray[uRow], delimeterStr); // This works just fine if I stop here
        // strcat(pLocalArray[uRow], buff); // ***** If I uncomment out this line, it throws a heap exception

        std::cout << "Check 3 -- Output is: " << pLocalArray[uRow] << endl; // Output: MyFirstString|MySecondString|MyThirdString;1704EB18-FE46-4AE4-A90F-06E42C3EE07A
        std::memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(buff));
        std::cout << "Check 4 -- Output is: " << pLocalArray[uRow] << endl; //Sanity check - MyFirstString|MySecondString|MyThirdString;1704EB18-FE46-4AE4-A90F-06E42C3EE07A
    }
    else
    {
        const char* test = "MyFirstString|MySecondString|MyThirdString";
        memcpy(buff, test, 43);
        pLocalArray[uRow] = _strdup(buff);

        std::cout << "Check -- Output is: " << pLocalArray[uRow] << endl; // Output: MyFirstString|MySecondString|MyThirdString
        std::memset(buff, '\0', sizeof(buff));
        std::cout << "Check 2 -- Output is: " << pLocalArray[uRow] << endl; //Sanity check - Output: MyFirstString|MySecondString|MyThirdString
    }
}
//...
```

However, as you can see from the comments, Its throwing an exception when I use the second `strcat` call.  I'm not understanding why doing the `strcat` on the delimiter is working just fine, but appending the delimiter and then immediately appending the GUID string does not work. Can someone point out to me what I'm doing incorrectly or not taking into account?

Comment: Use std::string and std::vector.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I would absolutely LOVE to If I had the option of using `std::string`, as this wouldn't be an issue in the slightest. My problem unfortunately has to deal with the fact that I'm dealing with a codebase that wasn't written by me and I would have to heavily modify a LOT of this library in order to use std::string. For the sake of the argument, let's just say `std::string` is not an option at the moment. There's much more code outside of this snippet.

Comment: Are you sure the allocations in `pLocalArray` are big enough to hold the result?

Comment: What is the value of `numCols`? What is `uRow`? Shouldn't it be `uCol`? Show the allocation of `pLocalArray`. Also try to make the example complete, you will really get the answer faster if it will be possible to just copy paste your code, compile, and then run.

Comment: Not only `pLocalArray` has to be allocated (up to `uRow`), but `pLocalArray[uRow]` must also be with a large enough size. An you do not show those parts...

Comment: @Ext3h Yes, the problem isn't the length of result, for example if I modify `"MyFirstString|MySecondString|MyThirdString` to "MyFirstString|MySecondString|MyThirdStringasdfjkldsajfl;kdsj;flsjaskdjfklsdjflkjdsljfjdslfkjlsadjkfjdjsakfljafljldsa;fkjfljksjf;dsjflsdkjdjs"` it works just fine.

Comment: `//... pLocalArray is allocated` Please show this part.

Comment: @KamilCuk will update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding how the `strdup` function works. In the following line:

```c
    pLocalArray[uRow] = _strdup(buff);
```

which is called to *initially* allocate memory for `pLocalArray[uRow]`, the amount of space allocated will be **the actual length of the `buff` string**, interpreted as a `nul`-terminated character array; this will be the length of the `"MyFirstString|MySecondString|MyThirdString"` literal, rather than the specified size of the `buff` array.

Then, when you later try to append a string to that, you are overflowing the allocated space (your first `strcat` only *seems* to work, but it is nevertheless undefined behaviour).

To allow space for up to 511 characters (plus the `nul`-terminator), you will need code like the following:

```c
    pLocalArray[uRow] = malloc(sizeof(buff)); // Allocate full size of "buff"
    strcpy(pLocalArray[uRow], buff); // then copy the strung data
```

Comment: Ah! This is the problem - Thanks for that, while the use of strdup was intended, I didn't know that it was allocated to the true length of the `buff` string. Thanks so much for pointing this out.